# Ingest messages from mobile client app, through BEAM, to Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm working on a personal project to get familiar with a number of Google/GCP projects and services (Flutter/Dart, Firestore, Cloud Functions, PubSub, Dataflow/BEAM).

For context on the "toy" problem I'm solving, imagine a mobile/cloud-based [Ouija board](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ouija):

> a board printed with letters, numbers, and other signs, to which a planchette or movable indicator points, supposedly in answer to questions from people at a seance.

Mobile users can create a board, share the link with friends, and collectively ask the board simple questions (e.g., "Does Suzie have a crush on Johnny?").  Players on the same board gesture in the UI to coax the Oiuja "indicator" to the answer in a "crowd-sourced" way.  [apache-beam](/questions/tagged/apache-beam) gives me the tools to group/window/process the streams of user data before writing to firestore.

The current *technical* question I'm wrestling with is:  What is a "low code" + lowest latency pattern to use to send the messages from the mobile app, into a BEAM pipeline for processing (which ultimately changes Document properties on a Firestore database).

I have 3 Options in mind depicted in the following diagram:
[image]

OPTION 1:  Mobile app uses Cloud Functions, which accept the payload and publish to a PubSub topic. This was my initial idea, but as I started to look at it closer, I questioned whether the Cloud Function is even necessary.  Enter option 2

OPTION 2:  Remove the Cloud Function and have the UI directly publish to the PubSub topic.  As I looked into the docs, it seemed like PubSub was meant to be harnessed server-side, so maybe I still need the Cloud Function?  Or maybe I lean into Firebase more... Enter option 3

OPTION 3:  Have the client only post messages through Firebase, and use Cloud Functions to pick these messages up and push into PubSub and/or BEAM. Advantage is I can benefit from the "offline" handling Firestore client gives me, but this feels like the worst-case for latency.

Am I missing something?  Is this question too much of an "opinion" question?

Thanks in advance.

Here's a [link to the Google Diagram](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1D5Jbpy7voeA2qOUchR5kMdl5B_ZsAsPy1BPtuOc_RNQ/edit?usp=sharing)

EDITS
So after thinking things through more, Authentication/Authorization is another consideration:

OPTION 2 - I would have to ask Google Account users to give permission to use "Pub/Sub", which feels like a bad UX.  Users don't know what "Pub/Sub" is!!  Option 1 would allow me to put in a service account from Cloud Function to Pub/Sub... and also use other Authentication providers besides Google.

OPTION 1 - I still need some kind of security at the Cloud Function layer to prevent bad actors.

Comment: Any reason why you're not considering calling into Firestore directly from your Beam pipeline?

Comment: I will call into Firestore from BEAM to store final data and then display on UI.  Its the path for writing the data in (that needs some stream processing in BEAM first) that I'm not sure about.  I like PubSub in front of BEAM to give me flexibility to send the data raw data somewhere else for long term store (and to use the existing PubSubIO source from BEAM).